# Does the Dell OptiPlex 330 have virtualization support?

Tags: virtualization

I tried to find in BIOS settings but I couldn't find option to enable virtualization.

It using **`Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E4600 240 GH: 2.40 GHz`**

I tried `updating BIOS`  to latest version but couldn't help.
So does the model `Dell OptiPlex 330` have **virtualization support?**

Comment: Try checking with tools like CPU-Z. Besides, every system supports virtualization. You're probably looking for hardware supported virtualization. As said system information tools like the mentioned CPU-Z will tell you more. ("VT-x" is the Intel CPU support for virtualization, see here for more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization )

Comment: Your CPU probably does not support it. What CPU is it?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks I've checked it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So does the model Dell OptiPlex 330 have virtualization support?

Your processor does not actually support VT-x which means you will be unable to enable it. `VT-x` is `Intel Hardware Virtualization`

If there is an option to enable `Hardware Virtualization` you should enable it.  However, [your processor does not actually support VT-x](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/32242/intel-core-2-duo-processor-e4600-2m-cache-2-40-ghz-800-mhz-fsb.html), so  an option exists within the firmware cannot be enabled.

> [image]